# Trouble using the getTime function

Tags: monads, daml

I am using getTime inside an assert statement on a contract choice as follows:

```
Add_Car : CarId
        with
            startCoverage: Time
        do
          -- Check for a legal start date
          assert (
            startCoverage > getTime
            )
          create this with datetime_vehicle_added = startCoverage, covered=True
```

It generates an error:

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Time' with actual type `m0 Time'
    * In the second argument of `(>)', namely `getTime'
      In the first argument of `assert', namely
        `(startCoverage > getTime)'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: assert (startCoverage > getTime)
```

Does getTime not return a value of type 'Time'?  what is 'mo Time'?

Answer (score 2):

`getTime` only makes sense as part of a transaction where there is a concept of ledger time. The `m0` is a type variable which refers to either an `Update` or `Scenario`, depending on your context. In practice, this simply means that you need to bind the result of `getTime` to a variable inside your `do` block:

```
do
  currentTime <- getTime
  assert ( startCoverage > currentTime )
```

Answer (score 2):

**tldr:** Per @bame, you need to bind the result of `getTime` in an `Update`
or `Scenario` do-block. ie.

```
Add_Car : CarId
  with
    startCoverage: Time
  do
  -- Check for a legal start date
  now <- getTime
  assert $ startCoverage > now
  create this with datetime_vehicle_added = startCoverage, covered=True
```

To understand what has happened here we need to start with the type of
`getTime`:

```
getTime : (HasTime m) => m Time
```

The type signature of the function you were expecting is one of:

```
getTimeValue : Time

getTimeFunc : () -> Time
```

To understand the difference you need to consider the concepts of purity
and encapsulation.

#### Purity

In DAML all functions are pure.

A pure function is a function which can be described completely in terms of
a mapping between values passed as arguments, to values returned as a
result. Values are concrete things such as Time, Int, Text, etc, and Lists,
Records, and Variants of values as well as a few other things I'll get to 
later. `getTimeValue` is a value, so it is by definition a constant, which
will only be the "current time" in the "stopped clock" sense.

`getTimeFunc` is a function that takes an argument of type `Unit`, which
means there is exactly one argument you can pass to it: `()`. Because the
function is pure, this means it cannot consider anything outside of its
argument, so this function must also return a constant value. In fact the
only difference between `getTimeValue` and `getTimeFunc` is that you must
pass `getTimeFunc` `()` to get the constant.

#### Encapsulation

That there is an outside world with a concept of "current time" that you
can interrogate and use is a "Context" that means any function that uses
this can no longer be described *completely* in terms of input -> output.
This is described as "impure".

In DAML all functions are pure, so if we want to handle "impurity" we have
to encapsulate the impurity in a pure value. In DAML we express this
encapsuation as a type thus:

```
encapsulatedImpureValue : m a
```

so in our case, where the value is a `Time` value :

```
encapsulatedImpureTimeValue : m Time
```

You can read this as, an encapsulated value of type `Time` that depends on
a context `m` to evaluate. As we have not mentioned anything about the
context `m` besides that it exists this is not quite enough to allow us to
implement it. Specifically, we need to also say that the context has to be
one with a concept of "the current time", which is how we end up with the
signature of `getTime` in the DAML standard library:

```
getTime : (HasTime m) => m Time
```

Which you can read as: an encapsulated value of time `Time` that depends on
a context `m` that supports `HasTime` (ie. the concept of "current time").

#### Using Encapsulated Values

We can now write:

```
let now = getTime
```

and `now` will be a pure **encapsulated** value — which is not immediately
useful, as any attempt to use it in any function expecting a pure `Time`
value will fail, as that would require breaking the encapsulation, and DAML
stricly enforces encapsulation violations as compilation errors.

To use an encapsulated value you must first specify a suitable context, and
then *run* the value within that context.  DAML provides two contexts that
support `HasTime`: `Update` and `Scenario`. It also provides one way to run
a `Scenario` wrapped values, and one way to run `Update` wrapped values,
and two ways to convert `Update` values into `Scenario` values.

1. Each toplevel Scenario value in a DAML module will be run by the DAML
   interpreter as a DAML test.
2. The body of each DAML Template Choice is defined to be an `Update` value
   that will be run when the choice is exercised.
3. You can use the `submit`, and `submitMustFail` functions to produce a
   `Scenario` value that, when run, will run an `Update` value authorized as
   the nominated `Party`.

#### Composing Encapsulated Values

There are a number of standard APIs that are common to almost all
functional languages for composing encapsulated values into compound
values. You will have heard of the most famous: "Functor" and "Monad"
These define functions that take encapsulated values and functions and
combine them in various ways. Encapsulation is such a fundamental software
engineering principle that it shouldn't be surprising that most FP
languages provide syntactic sugar to make using these easier — and DAML is
no different.

An encapsulated value that is an instance of the Functor interface supports
the `fmap` function, for which DAML also provides as an infix operator `<$>`.

An encapsulated value that is an instance of the Monad interface (called
`Action` in DAML), supports the `fmap`, `pure`, and bind/flatMap functions.
DAML provides `return` as an alias for `pure`; and the `>>=` operator for
bind/flatMap. It also provides do-notation as syntactic sugar for `>>=` so:

```
do
  t <- getTime
  a <- useTime t
  combineWithTime a t
```

Produces a compound `Update` value that (when it runs), runs `getTime`,
passes the resulting value to `useTime` then passes both results to
`combineWithTime`. The result of this do-block is also encapsulated `Update` value,
so we don't break encapsulation because by the time we are running
`updateA/B/C` we have provided the encapsulation context to the enclosing
compound `Update` value.

If (as you do in your example) we make this `do` block the body of a
choice, then exercising the choice will run the compound update.
Alternatively, if we pass it to `submit` we can run it as a part of a
scenario. If you do neither (which can happen if, for instance, you have
two Update values, and use an if expression to choose between them), then
it will have no observable effect, because in DAML all functions are pure.