# How do I assert conditions inside a function in DAML?

Tags: daml

I have the following code:

```haskell
template Iou
  with
    issuer : Party
    owner : Party
    amount : Decimal
    currency : Text
  where
    signatory issuer

mergeIou : Iou -> Iou -> Iou
mergeIou a b =
--  assert $ a.issuer == b.issuer
--  assert $ a.owner == b.owner
--  assert $ a.currency == b.currency
  a with amount = a.amount + b.amount
```

When I uncomment any of the asserts I get the following error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Iou' with actual type `m0 ()'
    * In the expression:
        assert
          $ (DA.Internal.Record.getField @"issuer" a)
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `assert` has an impure effect, so can't be used in a pure
function like `mergeIou`. The easiest way to solve this is to change
mergeIou to have type `Iou -> Iou -> Update Iou` and put the function in a
do-block.

ie.

```
mergeIou : Iou -> Iou -> Update Iou
mergeIou a b = do
  assert $ a.issuer == b.issuer
  assert $ a.owner == b.owner
  assert $ a.currency == b.currency
  pure $ a with amount = a.amount + b.amount
```

If you need the function to be pure, you can't use `assert`. The simplest
alternative is to use `Optional` to make the failure explicit in the type:

```
mergeIou : Iou -> Iou -> Optional Iou
mergeIou a b = do
  unless (a.issuer == b.issuer) None
  unless (a.owner == b.owner) None
  unless (a.currency == b.currency) None
  pure $ a with amount = a.amount + b.amount
```

To aid with debugging I suggest you use `Either` instead, so you can
identify which of the assertions failed:

```
mergeIou : Iou -> Iou -> Either Text Iou
mergeIou a b = do
  unless (a.issuer == b.issuer) $ Left "IOU issuers did not match"
  unless (a.owner == b.owner) $ Left "IOU owners did not match"
  unless (a.currency == b.currency) $ Left "IOU currencies did not match"
  pure $ a with amount = a.amount + b.amount
```

For a fuller discussion of exactly what is going on here, I suggest you
read my extended answer to [Trouble using the getTime
function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792482/trouble-using-the-gettime-function/54798104#54798104)
where I discuss the concepts of purity and encapsulating ledger
interactions in DAML.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a way to define all three versions of `mergeIou` from @Recurse's answer in one go if you leverage DAML's `ActionFail` type class:

```
mergeIou : ActionFail m => Iou -> Iou -> m Iou
mergeIou a b = do
  unless (a.issuer == b.issuer) $ fail "IOU issuers did not match"
  unless (a.owner == b.owner) $ fail "IOU owners did not match"
  unless (a.currency == b.currency) $ fail "IOU currencies did not match"
  pure $ a with amount = a.amount + b.amount
```